# Typescript - node js - Missing initializer in const declaration

Tags: node.js, typescript, constants, declaration

Getting syntax error for below line of code.
SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

```js
const testMap : Map<string, any> = new Map();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your code is being interpreted as JavaScript, not TypeScript. Change your file extension to `.ts` instead of `.js`, and make sure your Node environment is set up to interpret it properly (such as with [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node))